# Transforming crime rates

Tags: transformation, spss

I am working on a project using campus crime rates as the independent variable. The data is highly positively skewed. I need to transform the data in order to achieve normal distribution to run OLS. However, I know that if I do a log transformation I will lose all instances where the crime rates are 0 (representing an absence of crime). What are other possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

While you could avoid the loss of cases by calculating something like log(1+rate), the nonnegativity boundis likely to cause trouble anyway.  You might consider using a generalized linear model (Analyze > Generalized Linear Models) with a gamma with log link response scale.  This can deal with the right-skew issue as well.

Note, though, that it is the error that carries the normality assumption in OLS regression, not the dependent variable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to clarify, if the overall model itself meets the normality assumption - proven thru a Shapiro-Wilk test based on the residuals, I do not need to be concerned with normalizing the raw data?

Comment: If the expected number of crimes is, say, 1 or zero, then the residual is severely bounded on one side, so a linear model is going to be wrong there.  That's why I suggested gamma with log link.